# Get time value only from timestamp values

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am fetching dateLocal variable as **"2013-04-18T12:25:00.000"**
How can I retrieve only **12:25:00.000** in this ?

I am calling this value in below code

```
echo $flightstatus->arrivalDate->dateLocal,"<br>";
```

Comment: [php.net datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: could you do a `var_dump($flightstatus->arrivalDate->dateLocal);` and post the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to achieve this

```
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($flightstatus->arrivalDate->dateLocal));
```

this will output

```
12:25:00
```

Comment: I have tried that before . it says Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in line 11

Comment: Cast the dateLocal object to string `echo date('H:i:s',strtotime((string)$flightstatus->arrivalDate->dateLocal));`